# How to use GnuPlot to plot a time series chart from a CSV file date and time stored in separate columns?

Tags: datetime, csv, gnuplot

Lets' take this as the data file:

```
2012-06-01, 01:00, 1
2012-06-01, 02:00, 2
2012-06-01, 03:00, 4
2012-06-01, 04:00, 3
...
2012-06-02, 01:00, 5
2012-06-02, 02:00, 2
2012-06-02, 03:00, 1
2012-06-02, 04:00, 1
...
```

I know how to set `timefmt` and `xdata` to plot time series when date and time are represented with a single field, but how to plot this with GnuPlot when time and date are stored in separate columns?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not too differently than you would if they were spaces...

```
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M'
set xdata time
set datafile sep ','
plot 'test.dat' u 1:3 w lines
```

I don't know if you've used timefmt with spaces in it before either (for regular space separated datafiles) but in that case, you specify the column where the time-data starts -- gnuplot automatically looks however many columns it needs to fill out the full time format.  Of course, you need a full using specification (in this case that means designating that the data is in the 3rd column -- note, not the second as you might expect).

(tested on gnuplot 4.4 -- OS X)

Comment: Right now I use comma-separated data files, ISO-8601 date-time format (like 2012-06-06T14:54Z) and no spaces at all. But I am going to need need to support space-separated and comma-separated date-time values in comma-separated files. Thank you for the solution, I will try it.

Answer (score 5):

Running Arch Linux
Gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 3

I couldn't get mgilson's code snippet to work.
I needed to set the `xrange` before it would stop complaining

```
all points y value undefined!
```

I had to

```
set xrange["2012-06-01, 01:00":"2012-06-02, 05:00"]
```

and finally got a pretty plot

Comment: Please post that as a comment to mgilson's answer, it is not an answer on its own. And for me his snippet works fine with 4.6.3 (Debian).